# Hibernate generates invalid query

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data @Query annotation to select some values from the database. The query look like this (simplified)

```
@Query("from #{#entityName} where :myParam is null or someAttribute not in :myParam")
```

This should create equivalent SQL that should return all records from the table if the myParam value is null, however hibernate create the where clause like this

```
... where :myParam = null or ...
```

which does not return anything.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM).
Hibernate configuration is like this:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

How can I ensure that the Hibernate generates correct query (i.e. using 'is' instead of '=')?

Comment: *Why* are you checking `NULL IS NULL` in the first place?

Comment: On a separate note, why are you still running the RTM version of SQL Server 2017? What do you have against patching? 2017 has had several security fixes in the last 3 years; there's rarely (never) any excuse for not updating your software for 3 years.

Comment: You _already have_ that query; it's called `findAll()`.

Comment: I've clarified the query a little bit. In case the parameter is present I need to fetch all records that match the query parameter, in case the parameter is null I need to return all records.

Comment: @Larnu I do not have control over the database unfortunately, I can only access it. Otherwise I would be using postgres.

Answer (score 0):

since JPA supports `coalesce` why not
`@Query("from #{#entityName} where coalesce(someAttribute, :myParam) = :myParam)`
?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add `nativeQuery = true` to `@Query` annotation, the query must be a valid JPQL query and it's the JPA's implementor's responsability (hibernate) to translate JPQL queries to underlying database SQL dialect.

With `nativeQuery = true` you must supply a valid SQL query that conforms to the underlying database dialect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be really surprised if this is really what is happening. My guess, your `@Query` annotation is not picked up and Spring Data uses the method name convention or you didn't share the correct query. Either way, if this really is a hibernate bug(maybe you are using a very old hibernate version), you should create an issue with a test case that reproduces the issue: http://hibernate.atlassian.net

Comment: I am starting to think that the problem is not with Hibernate. I've just found out that on linux it works correctly (i.e. generating IS operator) but on Windows it does not work (generating the '=' operator).